# Can you practice MSSQL queries on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to practice writing simple SQL queries but I can't connect to my school account on Microsoft SQL Server Studio because they delete your database once you finish the class. I downloaded MySQL but I wasn't sure if I could practice queries on it or not. Any answers would be great, thanks!

Comment: One option here: Save your create table and insert scripts in a separate text file, so that you can easily recreate your environment.

Comment: Make sure you download MySQL 8 so that you have access to CTEs and window functions.

Comment: If you need to test something is still SQL Server compatible you can use [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019)

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server have partially very different syntax and features

Comment: You can make database on text file using .sql extension and then you can use your database anytime you want and then their is no any problem like delete DB etc. Any time you want to make changes in your DB. You can change in your SQL file and run or update on SQL server or MySQL.

Comment: sql server is free anyway so why would you try to port to mysql.

Comment: This question is not appropriate for Stack Overflow -- either opinion based or because it seems to be requesting an off-set recommendation.  I'm surprised it has no close votes and lots of upvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax and built-in functions are not identical, but they are similar for many things. For example, [SQL TOP, LIMIT, or ROWNUM clauses](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp) is a case where they diverge.

Personally, I’d recommend taking a look at what [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/) has for SQL (and MySQL) resources. They have a ton of info to get you going, tutorials, references, etc. They also have “Try It Yourself” modules where you can use a playground database they provide to practice executing in the language your looking at material for. In cases where the SQL Server and MySQL (and other languages) syntax differs, w3schools shows examples of both (all that they support) like in the example I mentioned at the top.

Snippet from the top of their SQL tutorial home page:
“Our SQL tutorial will teach you how to use SQL in: MySQL, SQL Server, MS Access, Oracle, Sybase, Informix, Postgres, and other database systems.”

Answer (score 1):

I suggest SQLite. Why?

It is an embedded database, rather than something like MySql which stores folders of metadata. Sqlite stores only a single file. My reasons for beginning with Sqlite are as follows:

1) It is the default database for a lot of common applications (Django, Airflow, etc). Knowing it would come in real handy when learning these tools.

2) The download is not only much simpler, but the ide is much faster. Your complete database is also only a single file (very beginner friendly).

3) In memory databases. That's correct, you can spawn and delete databases in Sqlite within memory (or even delete the whole file with your OS file removal). Very useful for learning, data science, and on the fly OLAP.

4) It can store up to 140 TB of data. It is the perfect tool to load a csv to quickly analyze the data. Also, you can create a small database, compress the file, and send it to anyone! Sharing your whole database is really just sharing a file.

5) You can import sqlite into Python, C, C++, and start automating your queries. You can do this with MySQL too but there is more library downloading and reading to do. Do not use sqlite in production (multi threading limits) but it is great for ad hoc analysis (Jupyter notebooks), prototyping, and learning.

Overall, mysql is not the best tool for beginners (it's not even used in production as much as Postgres or SQL server). It abstracts too much from the user to even understand what the database represents or the query engine. Also, Sqlite is closer to standard ANSI than MySQL in my opinion (given all the syntactic sugar). Learn Sqlite, move to postgres, and then explore all the nosql, blockchain, etc. If you ever face MySQL, you'll pick it up in minutes. I guarantee, you will have a much easier time picking up sqlite!

Comment: If this is for data science, don't waste your time on MySql unless your enterprise uses it. Start with sqlite, use pandas and in memory data structures. When you need faster processing, you'll move on to Spark, Redis, and other data structure management frameworks. But the best way to start is to use the sqlite library (part of the standard library), pandas, numpy, dask and begin there. If you need a UI, download the Sqlite editor. But you will quickly see the power of combining Python with SQL rather than using a UI. Best of luck